# Git remote add through 2 ssh servers

Tags: git, ssh

Using Git, how can I add a remote from my local machine to a virtual machine (for hosting) that is only accessible from a secondary machine?

So to access this machine I would normally have to ssh into the first, then ssh into the second from the first one.

Is there a way to `git remote add prod ssh://user@server1.co.uk > ssh://user@server2.co.uk/app-deployment.git` from my local machine?

Or will I have to set up another remote in the middle server with more hooks?

EDIT:
The working repository is on my local machine, but the --bare repository I want to add as a remote is on "server2", there's no repository or code on server1, but I can only reach "server2" through ssh from "server1".

Comment: You do it not at the Git level but with SSH: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+jump+host

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host , https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts , https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+jump+host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `server1` as an SSH jump host. On your local machine edit `~/.ssh/config` and add

```
Host server2
    ProxyJump user1@server1
    User user2
```

Test the configuration: from the local machine try

```
ssh server2
```

or

```
ssh user2@server2
```

If SSH successfully connects to `server2` "directly" from your local machine (not really directly but automatically connecting to `server1` and using it as a proxy) add it as a remote in Git repo:

```
git remote add prod ssh://user2@server2/repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
git remote add origin <user>@<remote-server>:/absolute/path/to/repistory
```

Comment: I should probably be more specific, I mean the working repository is on my local machine, but the --bare repository I want to add as a remote is on "server2", there's no repository or code on server1, but I can only reach "server2" through ssh from "server1".

Comment: my bad, I updated the response, it should be the remote server instead and the user for that server (ssh user)

Comment: No, sadly I can't connect to the remote from my local machine without ssh chaining through the other server...